# Beautifulsoup doesn't print out certain html classes

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to web scrape data from the NBA website, I'm starting with just trying to get the dates but whenever I try to print that specific date class, Python will only print out an empty array `[]`.

I've tried printing out the entire block that contains all the content and it works, but when I get to this specific date class it won't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?cal=all&region=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


content = soup.findAll('div', class_='ScheduleDay_sdTop__TqiPn')

print(content)
```

Comment: Without looking;  That page cannot be scraped with requests/bs because it uses javascript to fetch the data it shows.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is aren't inside HTML but loaded from one Json file:

```py
import requests

url = "https://cdn.nba.com/static/json/staticData/scheduleLeagueV2_1.json"

data = requests.get(url).json()
# print(data)

for g in data["leagueSchedule"]["gameDates"]:
    print(g["gameDate"])
    for gg in g["games"]:
        print(
            gg["homeTeam"]["teamName"],
            gg["homeTeam"]["teamCity"],
            " -- ",
            gg["awayTeam"]["teamName"],
            gg["awayTeam"]["teamCity"],
        )
```

Prints:

```
...

04/14/2024 00:00:00
Celtics Boston  --  Wizards Washington
Cavaliers Cleveland  --  Hornets Charlotte
Pacers Indiana  --  Hawks Atlanta
Heat Miami  --  Raptors Toronto
Knicks New York  --  Bulls Chicago
Magic Orlando  --  Bucks Milwaukee
76ers Philadelphia  --  Nets Brooklyn
Grizzlies Memphis  --  Nuggets Denver
Timberwolves Minnesota  --  Suns Phoenix
Pelicans New Orleans  --  Lakers Los Angeles
Thunder Oklahoma City  --  Mavericks Dallas
Spurs San Antonio  --  Pistons Detroit
Warriors Golden State  --  Jazz Utah
Clippers LA  --  Rockets Houston
Kings Sacramento  --  Trail Blazers Portland
```